# Confusion in proof for the Law of the Unconscious Statistician, discrete case

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, expected-value

**Background**

The Law of the Unconscious Statistician states that given the formula for $E[X] = \sum\limits_x xP(X=x)$, we can also determine the expectation for a function of $X$ as such:

$$E[g(x)] = \sum\limits_x g(x)P(X=x)$$

**Question**

On Wikipedia, there is a short proof for the discrete case.

[image]

But I fail to grasp what goes on between lines 2 and 3 in the calculation.

**What I do understand**

- $X,\ \  Y=g(X)$ are discrete random variables
- $x,\ \  y$ are values that $X, Y$ can take, respectively
- $f_X(X),\ \  f_Y(y)$ are probability mass functions, or more familiarly, $P(X=x),\ \  P(Y=y)$
- the goal of the proof is to represent $E[Y]$ in terms of $f_X(x)$ instead of $f_Y(y)$ as the former is known, and the latter is not

**What I don't understand**

The subscript under the second sum, $x \ : \ g(x)=y$ makes it so I don't understand what is being summed over.

Moreover, I don't understand how a factor inside a sum (from line 2) can be replaced with a second sum (in line 3).

Can this step of the proof be re-written in a way that is more clear?

Comment: Ask yourself how to calculate $\mathbb P(g(X)=y)$.  It is the sum of $\mathbb P(X=x)$ over those values of $x$ for which $g(x)=y$.  Apparently here $\mathbb P(X=x)$  is written as $f_X(x)$

Comment: @Henry - But how can they replace a factor inside the sum, with a sum outside the first sum? I mean, it's not generally true that $\sum\limits_x \left(xy\right) = \sum\limits_x x \cdot \sum\limits_x y$ right? Shouldn't there therefore be a parenthesis around the $y$ and the second sum in line 3?

Comment: Would you object to $\sum\limits_x \left(xy\right) = y \sum\limits_x x $?  Or   $\sum\limits_y\sum\limits_x \left(xy\right) = \sum\limits_y  \left(y\sum\limits_x x\right) $ ?  The third line is designed to be read as having brackets since the values of $x$ depend on the value of $y$

Comment: @Henry - I guess it's because I haven't done enough sigma summation, but I totally read the third line as being the product of two separate sums. So just to be clear, am I supposed to read the third line as $\sum\limits_y \left[y \sum\limits_{x:g(x)=y}f_X(x) \right]$?

Comment: Yes: otherwise the $\sum\limits_{x:g(x)=y}$ makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

IMO a clearer proof expresses the subscript "$x:g(x)=y$" in *indicator* form. The indicator $I(A)$ of a statement equals $1$ if statement $A$ is true, and equals zero otherwise.

First apply the definition of expectation to write
$$E[g(X)] = \sum _y y P(g(X)=y)\tag1
$$
where the sum is taken over all possible values $y$ for $Y$. Next, compute $P(g(X)=y)$ as the sum of $P(X=x)$ for all $x$ such that $g(x)=y$.
This is written
$$P(g(X)=y)=\sum_x P(X=x)I(g(x)=y),\tag2$$
i.e., we are summing the product of $P(X=x)$ with $I(g(x)=y)$ as $x$ ranges over all possible values for $X$. Substitute (2) into (1), and interchange the summations:
$$\begin{aligned}E[g(X)]&=\sum_y y \left(\sum_x P(X=x) I(g(x)=y)\right) \\
&= \sum_x \sum_y yP(X=x)  I(g(x)=y)\\
&=\sum_x P(X=x)\left(\sum_y yI(g(x)=y)\right)\\
&\stackrel{(*)}=\sum_x P(X=x)g(x)
\end{aligned}\tag3$$
To argue (*), observe that the expression $\sum_y yI(g(x)=y)$ is summing over all possible values of $y$. But as $y$ varies, the only time the indicator  $I(g(x)=y)$ lights up is when $y=g(x)$.